# Threading model change in MonoTouch 6.x?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.ios

Several weeks late, but I am finally getting back to updating my MonoTouch iOS app with the new 6.0 version. For long running activities (my application makes services calls to the background and does image uploads), I use threading very similar to the examples. This all worked great until I upgraded. A typical pattern in an a Controller would look like:

```
protected void LogInButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      NetworkActivity.Start();

      // start the request.
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((cb) => {

          var service = new ClientUserService();
          var result = service.Login(this.UserName.Text, this.Password.Text);

          // when done, switch back to UI.
          this.InvokeOnMainThread (() => {

              NetworkActivity.Stop();

              // do the various other things to init the app on the UI thread.
          }
      });
}
```

The worked great on 5.x and never crashed. And it followed the published code guidelines. But now I immediately get the exception of UUIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread. I get that on my service call line (service.Login(...)).

So... I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here. I did go back and look at some of the newer samples. Some of them are using the task library (for example https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/blob/master/MultiThreading/iOSMultiThreading/Screens/MainScreen_iPhone.cs), but that shouldn't preclude this QueueUserWorkItem method.

**Question**: did the threading model in Monotouch have a breaking change so that the above coding pattern is no longer supported?

Thanks. JB

Comment: Geez. `service.Login(this.UserName.Text, this.Password.Text)` was causing the issue because the controls are in the UI thread. Just wasn't thinking about correctly (this was older code too; so it was incorrect from the get-go). I did a code sweep and of course this was the only place that I was accessing UI controls after queuing up a thread. Just happened to be on login in (!). Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap this.UserName.Text and this.Password.Text in InvokeOnMainThread delegate. Monotouch expects that all work with UI elements is performed in the UI thread.

Comment: Or copy their contents to local variables prior to calling QueueUserWorkItem, sounds liked a cleaner solution to me, IMHO, though it doesn't really make that much of a difference unless the user edits really fast.

Comment: And I wouldn't call it a change in threading model, just bug fixes related to error reporting.  It's basically the standard pattern in many UI tool kits: you can only access UI related properties from the UI's main thread.  If earlier versions allowed this, then this looks like a missing error check to me.

Comment: Duh. I **clearly** see that now. I was getting away with it before, not really thinking of the accessor of the field as part of the UI thread context. Thanks. You're right, not so much a threading change. More of exposing a potential issue that I had.

Answer (score 3):

This feature was introduced a while ago in [MonoTouch 5.4](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.4) (see New Library Features, Cross-thread UI Checks).

Now this is not a *threading* change (the code is executed as before) but simply extra checks to ensure people are warned about a common pitfall - that was often pretty hard to debug.

There are instructions if you **want** the old behaviour back. However be warned that your current code is broken and, while it might work 99% of the time, it might break badly for some people (e.g. such issues are often timing dependent, changing your code or using different devices might trigger the issue).

As such I strongly suggest you to fix such issues as you find them (your users will love you for it ;-) just like Ben described.

Comment: It did work that way and did not crash (it's actually very stable), _but_ I am definitely doing it incorrectly :-) Just was odd to that it break so suddenly that I was assuming that the pattern for threading changed. There should only be a few places where I might have done this so it should be easy enough to update. Thanks!